# Javascript bookmarklet link works one 1 WP site but not the other

Tags: wordpress, bookmarklet

I created a post on my wordpress site and share several javascript bookmarklets.
2 of them perform a Google custom search once you enter a word into the dialog box.

Here is the code to one of them:

```
<a href='javascript:q = "" +(window.getSelection ?  window.getSelection() : document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text); if (!q) q = prompt("Find Royalty Free From Wikimedia, Simply enter a keyword into the box below", ""); if (q!=null) window.open("http://www.google.com/images?q= " +"\"I+grant+anyone+the+right+to+use+this+work+for+any+purpose%2C+without+any+conditions%2C+unless+such+conditions+are+required+by+law\" + " + escape(q).replace(/ /g, ""+"")) ; void 0' ;
            <font color="#000000">Wikimedia Images</font></a>
```

Now for some reason on my test site this worked fine, but when publishing on my personal blog it doesn't work.  test blog and personal blog are on different hosts and running different themes etc.

Any idea what would cause this problem?

If you like to see the post it's currently displayed on it's http://thewiseaffiliate.com/free-stuff/free-images-for-commercial-website/
scroll to bottom of post and you'll see a hyperlinked stackoverflow.

If I repeated the same process on my test site the hyperlink would load up the bookmarklet dialog box.

Here is the test site, smae code used on the Wikimedai hyperlink: http://hair.siterubix.com/hello-world

Any help on this is appreciated.